# TCP socket stays in established state after close by server

Tags: c++, tcp, boost-asio

There is a plenty of similar questions on Stackoverflow, I had checked most of them. It seems, I have some specific issue.

I have an application written in C++ using Boost ASIO. App listens for incoming connections and handles data flow from/to clients over TCP socket. On app exit, it closes all established connections (and stops listening for new connections). For some reason, in certain environment, client connection may stay in ESTABLISHED state (might be checked by "netstat -apn" command), despite all sockets are closed, according to logs.
Code responsible for disconnection:

```
boost::system::error_code tmpErrorCode;
if (mSocket.is_open())
{
    mSocket.shutdown(boost::asio::socket_base::shutdown_both, tmpErrorCode);
    mLog->info() << __FUNCTION__ << " for connection ID = " << mConnectionId << "; shutdown_both ErrCode: " << tmpErrorCode.message();

    mSocket.close(tmpErrorCode);
    mLog->info() << __FUNCTION__ << " for connection ID = " << mConnectionId << "; close ErrCode: " << tmpErrorCode.message();

    //callback to delete client identifier from server's list
    mServer->onDisconnect(mConnectionId);
}
```

On all environments, it prints like

```
[2018-04-02 13:54:33.184472] [info] disconnect for connection ID = 1; shutdown_both ErrCode: Success (0)
[2018-04-02 13:54:33.184478] [info] disconnect for connection ID = 1; close ErrCode: Success (0)
```

So socket is expected to be closed, while it might stay ESTABLISHED (rarely, but still).

What is more interesting, behaviour could be reproduced only on one environment (I have 3 servers running the same application under CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708). On two others connection always goes to TIME_WAIT, as expected.

sysctl.conf is identical on all servers.

I feel a bit confused and would be grateful if someone could point me some direction for further research of problem source.

UPDATE: after some simplified tests and ports state monitoring I came to the following points.
1) Issue is never reproduced with client which cares about his connection validity.
2) Server application is never leaves ports in incorrect state (TIME_WAIT always).
3) After a few hours of staying disconnected, clients suddenly became having ESTABLISHED connection with nothing (server app is off during all that time). We suspected some "phantom" software which could open port to listen, accept connection from client and drop connection, however I can't detect such app. So the only valid way is to fix client software, to make it handle connections properly. Nevertheless, it is still mystery for me, why client connection may become ESTABLISHED a few hours after server is closed.

Comment: Can you come with a minimal selfcontained example? I'm willing to try it on CentOS if need be. But right now it's a wild goose chase because there's no way to tell why I'm getting the results I'm getting if I happen to to not reproduce the symptom

Comment: This can happen when there is still outbound data in the socket send buffer and the receiver isn't reading. The transition to TIME_WAIT can't happen until all the outbound data including the FIN has been sent and acknowledged.

Comment: Thank you sehe, I will try to reproduce issue using simplified applications.

Comment: Thank you EJP, does it mean server could do nothing more on shutdown if client is not reading, as you said?

Comment: Well, it could reset the connection, but then the pending data will be lost. Fix the client.

Comment: @EJP Clients are 3rd-party apps, and hardly would be fixed. Do you mean SO_LINGER option usage?